# Deploying ClickOnce via Mage and Visual Studio Publish Wizard

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, mage

We identified that when you deploy your clickonce project via MageUI.exe, the Setup.exe or Publish.htm does not being created.

Is there anyway I could create the Setup.exe with pre-requisites included at least? We could figure a way to create a HTML page. However if there is a way to create a complete deployment package way similar to Visual Studio's wizard that would be ideal.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for you, but instead of compiling the code and then calling mage to create the click once, you'll need to do this using msbuild.

Using MSBUILD, there's a publish target you can call to get this working.
E.x.: msbuild WindowsFormsApplication5.sln /t:publish

Comment: Thanks @hjb417 for replying. Will go through it and see what's in offer to me. Thanks again.